# Node vs Nodejs version

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to update node to version 7 but it is staying at v5.

[image]

Comment: Without more information, it's impossible to provide any help.  Please tell us about your operating system, how you initially installed Node.js, how you are trying to update it, etc.  On the last note, show exactly what you typed, and the exact console output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably with the same problem as him: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695155/node-nodejs-have-different-version)

If you run `which node` and `which nodejs` on your terminal you should get 2 different paths.

And, if this is the case, you can remove one of your node apps and symlink the other.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nodejs
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
```

> It's explained in the first answer on the link above what is happening.