# node -v and nodejs -v shows different versions

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, node-modules

node -v and nodejs -v shows different versions

My node -v shows
4.2 version 
and nodejs -v
shows 6.10.3

So what should be the issue?
I want node -v to show 6.10.3.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742961/node-vs-nodejs-version

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem, and I solved this by doing the following steps.

Step 1: completely remove node and node js from system

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Then go to **/etc/apt/sources.list.d** and remove any node list if you have. Then update system cache by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step2: Installing Specific version of node (I am using node version 8)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Now If you see node -v and nodejs -v, you get both the versions are same as

```
v8.14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

i also face this problem

i tried this

1) sudo apt-get remove nodejs sudo apt-get remove npm

remove cache from  /etc/apt/sources.list.d

2)sudo apt-get update

then install again nodejs

3)sudo apt install nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed both `nodejs` and `nodejs-legacy` packages. So just remove one of them. `nodejs-legacy` is v.4.x and `nodejs` is v.6.x

```
apt-get remove nodejs-legacy
```

If it says there is no "nodejs-legacy" try

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

And you will see it in the list when it asks you if you are sure about uninstalling.